# How do I change the name of app when installing?

Tags: android

How can I change the app name when installing? Once installed my app name on the icon is correct and everything else is in place.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Sorry I'm not being clear.
I started a project with the app name as Simple Counter but now it's something else. When I build the APK and install it the name appears as Counting App.

[image]

Comment: You can't change it after installed...

Comment: what are you trying to say? do you want to change the app name at runtime? (you can't) or are you saying that the icon in the installation window is different from the icon in the home screen?

Comment: This is an app that I made. So I'm wondering how I can make the App Name during installation my apps actual name.

Comment: I started off making the app called Counting App

Answer (score 1):

In the AndroidManifest.xml, there should be an `<application>` tag with a `android:name` attribute. This is where you set the name which appears below the icon in the device's launcher. You will also see that each `<activity>` tag has a `android:label` attribute. This is the text which is shown in the tool bar when that activity is active. Both of these attributes can be set using a string resource. This allows you to make a single change to your code in order to update both places where the string is displayed. It also allows you to provide translations in other languages.

If you make these changes and they still stay the same when you run your app from Android Studio, you should turn off Instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

For this, uninstall your application from your device, after that clean all caches files. Then try to install the application again.